I need accurate screen cordinates to pass for magnifer widget in Flutter
This is with the magic numbers  This is without magic numbers I am trying to add raw magnifier widget on the google map marker which activates when marker is dragged, i cannot wrap the marker as it is not a flutter widget i tried passing cordinates to the widget using google controller screen cordinates they worked but they are not accurate and varries from device to device , then i tried gesture detector but after using it dosent allow me to navigate on map or drag the marker also tried hit behviour translucent , next i tries listener but it is also not accurate and dosent work while dragging is THERE ANY OTHER WAY WHICH MIGHT WORK?
Future<void> _handleDrag(LatLng newPosition) async {
    _lastMarkerPosition = newPosition;
    GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate =
        await controller.getScreenCoordinate(newPosition);
    print(
        'Screen coordinates: x=${screenCoordinate.x}, y=${screenCoordinate.y}');

    // Update state with new screen coordinates
    setState(() {
      _left = screenCoordinate.x.toDouble() / 1.9 - 60;
      _top = screenCoordinate.y.toDouble() / 1.9 - 45;
    });
  }

`
: Stack(children: [
            GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              initialCameraPosition: gblFactoryLocation,
              compassEnabled: false,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              polylines: _polyline,
              // If empty, returns error

              //CODE//
              onTap: (position) {
                if (isAddingPlot) {
                  int index_element = 0;
                  setState(() {
                    Marker newMarker = Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId(position.toString()),
                        position: position,
                        draggable: true,
                        onDrag: _handleDrag,
                        // rotation: 180,
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueCyan),
                        consumeTapEvents: false,
                        onDragStart: (oldPosition) {
                          isMagnifierVisible = true;
                          // Finding nearest marker (Since its not accurate)
                          double distance = calculateDistance(
                              oldPosition.latitude,
                              oldPosition.longitude,
                              new_polygon.points[0].latitude,
                              new_polygon.points[0].longitude);

                          for (var i = 0;
                              i < new_polygon.points.length;
                              i++) {
                            double dist = calculateDistance(
                                oldPosition.latitude,
                                oldPosition.longitude,
                                new_polygon.points[i].latitude,
                                new_polygon.points[i].longitude);
                            if (dist < distance) {
                              index_element = i;
                              distance = dist;
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        onDragEnd: (position) {
                          isMagnifierVisible = false;
                          new_polygon.points.removeAt(index_element);
                          new_polygon.points.insert(
                              index_element,
                              LatLng(
                                  position.latitude, position.longitude));

                           // CODE//
                               
            Positioned(
              left: _left,
              top: _top,
              child: isMagnifierVisible
                  ? const RawMagnifier(
                      decoration: MagnifierDecoration(
                        shape: CircleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink, width: 3),
                        ),
                      ),
                      size: Size(140, 140),
                      magnificationScale: 2,
                    )
                  : SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),`


"next i tries listener but it is also not accurate and dosent work while dragging" - what do you mean by "not accurate" - how events received by Listener widget can be not accurate?

@pskink by not accurate I meant when I used listener widget and click on the screen the magnifier would appear something like 50pixel offset and also it didn't give me continuous coordinates

and what is that magic number 1.9 in _left = screenCoordinate.x.toDouble() / 1.9 - 60;? why 1.9?

@pskink that was adjusting offset for my device  I realized late that it will not work for other devices

so you have the answer: you are getting wrong results because of those "magic number  calculations"

@pskink why do you think i put them in the first place? because the results are not accurate i guess that is because of pixel ratio or something not sure ?but again my concern is that it sould work on all devices with different screen size

no, pixel ratio has nothing to do with that, this is magic 1.9 that makes all your problems

please check the question i've added some screenshots @pskink

check https://gist.github.com/pskink/a345ca298bd1352ac2f014f148763c42 - as you can see no magic numbers are used and still everything is shown properly using Listener.onPointer* callbacks
